# How do I reliably handle right-to-left text between AWS s3 and node.js?

Tags: amazon-s3, text, right-to-left

I have a text file located on AWS s3 which is written in Arabic. I've been told that the text is set to be displayed right-to-left. When I download that file at the terminal and open it in Emacs, the text is indeed displayed right-to-left and the first line looks like this:
[image: pic of emacs rendering arabic text file]

But when I use Node.js to download that file from s3 and try to view the first line, it's not the same:
[image: node console log of the first line of that file]

My code is below. I would have assumed that the `toString()` method is the culprit but having played around with `toLocaleString()` and various language arguments I couldn't make them consistent. I see that s3 has `ContentLanguage` and `ContentEncoding` fields which are both undefined for this object. What am I doing wrong?

```js
      const ob = await s3.getObject({
        Bucket, Key
      }).promise(),
      text = ob.Body.toString('utf-8'),
      data = text.split('\n').filter(e => e.match(/\S/));

      console.info(JSON.stringify(data.slice(0, 2), null, 5));
```

As a workaround, I do this:

```js
      data = text.split('\n').filter(e => e.match(/\S/))
        .map(line => [`ar`, `he`].includes(lng) ?
          line.split("").reverse().join("") : // <-- arabic & hebrew right-to-left rtl
          line)
```

But I'm not clear if that's best.

Comment: It looks like you're comparing how some text editor displays a file vs how Chrome's dev console displays some text.  Is the question how to get `console.info` to display RTL text correctly?

Comment: It's in Node.js -- downloading the file from s3 manually and displaying it in a rtl-aware editor displays the content correctly. Downloading it with Node.js and displaying the first line doesn't seem to match without including a manual `reverse` which seems hacky. This is the case before any browser gets it, no Chrome etc..

Comment: How are you displaying the single line from Node js?